# create a reusable component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, simplify, generalization

How do I make my vue.js component more general and reusable and can pass only the neccessary data?

this is what I want to build:

[image]

### Structure:

- the component has a header
- the component has different inputs
- the component has a submit button
- the component has a list as a footer - that is passed depending on the input

### My Approach

#### the parent

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Component A -->
    <SettingsCard
     :listA="listA"
     cardType="CompA"
    >
     <template v-slot:header>
       Foo - Component A
     </template>
    </SettingsCard>

    <!-- Component B -->
    <SettingsCard
     :listB="listB"
     cardType="CompB"
    >
     <template v-slot:header>
       Bar - Component B
     </template>
    </SettingsCard>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### the child:

```html
// SettingsCard.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="header"></slot>

    <div v-if="cardType === 'CompA'">
     <!-- Show input and submit button for component a -->
    </div>

    <div v-if="cardType === 'CompB'">
     <!-- Show input and submit button for component b -->
    </div>

    <ListComponent
     :cardType="cardType"
     :list="computedList"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    cardType: String, // for the v-if conditions
    listA: Array,
    ListB: Array
  },
  data() {
   return {
      namefromCompA: '', // input from component A
      namefromCompB: ''  // input from component B
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedList() {
      // returns an array and pass as prop the the card footer
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### The problems

1. I have `undefined` props and `unused` data in my SettingsCard.vue component

```js
// CompA:
props: {
 cardType: 'compA',
 listA: [1, 2, 3], // comes from the parent
 listB: undefined // how to prevent the undefined?
}
```

```js
// CompA:
data() {
  return {
    namefromCompA: 'hello world',
    namefromCompB: '' // unused - please remove me
  }
}
```

2. to use `v-if="cardType === 'compA'"` feels wrong

Do you have a better approach in mind to make this component reusable and remove anything unnecessary?

Answer (score 2):

use a method instead of `"cardType === 'CompA'"`.

just try this in your `SettingsCard.vue`

```js
methods: {
    showMeWhen(type) {
      return this.cardType === type;
    },
  },
}
```

and your v-if render condition would be like:
`v-if="showMeWhen('compA')"`

---

### update

for exmaple in your `namefromCompA/B` you can just pass a new prop to display the correct name.

```js
props: {
    cardType: String, // for the v-if conditions
    listA: Array,
    ListB: Array,
    namefromComponent: {
        type: String,
        default: 'NoName'
    }
  },
```

then in your usage you just pass it like you do with the other props.

```html
<SettingsCard
     :listB="listB"
     cardType="CompB"
     namefrom-component="my Name for component B"
    >
```

Comment: thank you - do you also have a suggestion how I remove the unused properties and data?

Comment: @wittgenstein i don't understand what you mean. why not simple delete unused stuff and for your  `undefined` set a default https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: `Why not just delete unused stuff"` - that's what I'm looking for. How can I delete unused reactive data variables? I think I need to restructure my component architecture.

Comment: As a addition: There must be a way to avoid creating the instances in the first place. This will spare you from deleting afterwards...